# Add the share button to (other) answers in review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, answers, permalink

When reviewing an answer in one of the *Low Quality Posts*, *First Posts*, or *Late Answers* queues, there is the option to watch the `Other answers` of the question. This gives a more *"naked"* view of the answers compared to the regular question's page. For example:

| From review | From original post |
| --- | --- |
| [image: An answer showed in the Other answers tab of the review queue] | [image: The same answer from the original question's page showing the buttons available under the answer] |

I can understand the reason: we don't want reviewers to be editing or flagging other answers - *they should focus on reviewing the answer at hand*.

**But**, sometimes I find it useful to link to other answers in a comment to the **reviewed** answer. Specifically, when someone posts a late answer repeating the same ideas from older answers.

Can we have the share button (or any other way to obtain a permalink to a specific answer) available in the "other answers" tab as well, so we can get a link ***directly from the review page*** (that is, instead of needing to open the question in a new tab, go the answer, copy its link, go back to the review and paste the link)?

Comment: How often does this happen? It's perfectly possible to open the original question thread from the review. From there, sharing is a click away.

Comment: @Mast Sure. I was contemplating if to add this to the question but it felt like noise: I know it's just a few more clicks, but usually it means another tab and moving between tabs. Of course, it's not the most pressing request and doesn't happen all that much - but for the times it does happen, it makes it so much easier to stay in the same page and just copy with one click. I also have a feeling it is not such a technical overhead to implement so if we can make our lives easier in any way...

Comment: I didn't really like that the post tooling was included in the reviews, since they are supposed to laser focus you into some issue.

Answer (score 2):

So it's been a while since I asked for this and I finally found the time to create a userscript to do that. It still has some work to be done on it (as it's just the second one I ever wrote...), but it already serves its basic purpose. Here's how it looks with the script running:

[image]

It has a [StackApps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/9776/adding-the-share-button-for-other-answers-in-review-queues) and a [GitHub page](https://github.com/tomerkal/Share-link-adder). To install directly, use [this link](https://github.com/tomerkal/Share-link-adder/raw/main/share_adder.user.js).